# How much should one eat in Suhoor?

Tags: sunnah, ramadan, food

Should one eat a lot in Suhoor? Or should one eat in the normal manner (filling one-third of the stomach with food, one-third with water and one-third with air)?

I actually want to know if there is any Islamic source (like Quran Ayah or Hadeeth) that specify the amount to eat in the Suhoor.

Comment: I got a friend who eat fair amount(not makes him filled) of food after Maghrib. Then they pray Isha and Taraweeh and come back to eat again when they are hungry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not eat to much but just the right amount as before Ramadan. The ruling do not change because you are meant to feel the hunger than the poor feel everyday and so you should be grateful for what you have been blessed with. Also over eating has bad side effects. Those who show moderation in eating find greater pleasure in their food than those who overindulge.

**Allah** says:

> O children of Adam, take your adornment to every mosque. Eat and
>   drink, but be not excessive. Indeed, He does not like those who commit
>   excess. [[Sûrah al-A`râf: 31]](http://quran.com/7/31)

The hadith of the **prophet** (PBUH):

> The child of Adam fills no vessel worse than his stomach. Sufficient
>   for the child of Adam are a few morsels to keep his back straight. If
>   he must eat more, then a third should be for his food, a third for his
>   drink, and a third left for air. [[Sunan al-Tirmidhî](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/77) and Musnad Ahmad (17186) and authenticated by al-Albânî in Sahîh al-Jâmi`]

***Luqmân*** said to his son: “O my son! If the stomach is full, one’s mental processes go to sleep, one’s wisdom is dulled, and one’s limbs refrain from worship.”

***Umar*** observed: "Whoever eats a lot finds no pleasure in the remembrance of Allah."

Comment: Could you add references to where luqman said that to his son? Also to the sstatement of umar.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam-O-Alaykoum

I think you should eat as you've eaten in your normal days, i mean one-third of stomach filled, because if you eat more that this you're going to experience laziness especially if you get a sleep after Suhoor, this will make you off of you're worshiping during the day, try to eat completed nourishing foods like dates because they can keep you full of power during the whole day.

And Allah knows better.

Answer (score 0):

for me suhoor is just moving the eat time, from breakfast to suhoor. please note that Indonesian's breakfast portion is same as the lunch and dinner. so my answer is, just eat in normal manner.